# Model.base.modelSchemas undefined when upgrading to mongoose 6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We’ve been working with mongoose@^5.4.11 and due to the MongoDB Server upgrade to version 5, we are upgrading to mongoose@6.1.7.

In our code we have this line:

`Model.base.modelSchemas[modelName].paths`

after upgrading to 6.1.7 I get `undefined` for modelSchemas.

I cloned the mongoose repo for tag 5.4.11, and there modelSchemas is a property of the Mongoose class in ‘lib/index.js/’

I also cloned the mongoose repo for tag 6.1.7, and there modelSchemas is not defined anywhere (only see mentions of it in docs files)

In the mongoose [migration guide 5 to 6](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html) modelSchemas is not mentioned anywhere.

I think I have things working again by changing the code to:

`Model.base.model(modelName).schema.paths`

Could someone confirm this change is exactly equivalent to the original statement?